# Deleting and renaming a single column until a certain row in emacs

Tags: emacs

I have a LARGE emacs file. In that file there is a column that simply lists "B". I want to change that column to list "A". Is this possible to do in emacs without manually clicking and renaming? I don't know how to write a script for it so i'm not sure. I'm not the best programmer.

Answer (score 4):

The rectangle commands might work here.  Set the mark on the first line, in the column to change.  Then navigate to the last line, one column over.  Type <kbd>C-x r t</kbd> (`string-rectangle`) and enter "A" at the prompt in the minibuffer.  This will replace the text in the rectangle with corners defined by the point and mark with the text you've typed in the minibuffer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use <kbd>C-x r t</kbd> `inline-string-rectangle` function in magnars's mark-multiple package.

It works like original string-rectangle function but more intuitive way.

Check these pages.

[Emacs Rocks! YouTube Introduction]

http://emacsrocks.com/e08.html

[GitHub Project]

https://github.com/magnars/mark-multiple.el